# When a button is deactivated, it shows on top of fixed elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed header in my page, and many buttons. If the buttons are deactivated,

```
$(".myButtons").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

when I scroll down the page, instead of being hidden by the fixed header like everything else, they ghost above it. Anyone have any idea how this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Where is the HTML?  Fiddle?  CSS?  Is this specific to Bootstrap??

Answer (score 1):

it's probably some weird inherited CSS that sets z-index on the disabled button. You might be able to easily fix it with some added jQuery:

```
$('.myButtons').prop('disabled', 'disabled').css('z-index', 0);
```

(You can use .attr but jQuery is moving toward .prop to set attributes).

The better way to solve this issue would be to find the original style that sets the z-index. You can probably find it if you inspect the element and expand "Computed Styles" if you have that in your developer tools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: z-index was the problem. Thanks for bringing that up.I didn't know about that because I'm still pretty new to web programming. Unfortunately, trying to change the z-index of the buttons did not seem to do anything. I changed the z-index of the header to 10 and that eliminated the problem.

Comment: PS. I looked in computed styles and I couldn't find anything that set the z-index.

Comment: Yeah, often times z-index problems occur on the parent element so you might not see them in computed styles unless you're focused on the parent element. Usually I just start at the element I'm having issues with and traverse through each of its parents. Hopefully my answer helped.  (you should hit the up arrow on it if it did ;)